# Create test using Mocha/Chai/TypeScript that fails when a different amount or type of arguments is sent to a function

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am not sure if I understand chai correctly, but is there a way to test that a function will fail if it sent the wrong amount (or type) of arguments? For example:

```
expect( function(){
    let foo = new MyClass();
} ).to.throw('Error')
```

But MyClass() expects an argument in its definition, something like this:

```
class MyClass{
    name:string;
    constructor(name:string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it use [.throw([errorLike], [errMsgMatcher], [msg])](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) method.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    if (typeof name !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError('expect "string" type for "name" argument');
    }
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('63958704', () => {
  it('should throw error if no parameter passed in the constructor', () => {
    expect(() => new MyClass(1 as any)).to.throw('expect "string" type for "name" argument');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  63958704
    ✓ should throw error if no parameter passed in the constructor


  1 passing (43ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |       50 |     100 |      75 |                   
 index.ts |      75 |       50 |     100 |      75 | 7                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```